# Is there a way to animate this SVG with a gradient using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

So I found [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/c7/68/4bc7687858221c6b60d7b02fe0740670.png) image on Google and wanted to try and recreate this graphic and animate it. The part I am talking about is the Purple to Pink gradient waves at the top left of the image.

So far I have done [this](https://codepen.io/sweatycubes/pen/ExamPVb) but can't seem to get everything working as I want. Code below.

```
<div id='container'>
    <svg class='waves' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 150 28' preserveAspectRatio='none' shape-rendering='auto'>
        <defs>
            <path id='wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' />
        </defs>
        <g class='parallax'>
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='0' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='3' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='5' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='7' fill='#ffffff' />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Things that I can't accomplish are as followed:

1. The SVG needs to fill the whole 200x200 pixel box, not just the top.
2. The waves need to be filled with a Gradient. Since there will be 4 waves moving at different speeds, the gradient probably won't blend between the waves. I'm not sure on how to go about fixing that as the whole thing needs to look like 1 animated wave element. Maybe a static Gradient?
3. The wave SVG need to be resized somehow to look like this.

[image]

Comment: it seems that the gradient is a simple background and the SVGs are semi transparent so you can see the gradient. I don't think it's gradient applied to the waves

Comment: @TemaniAfif Currently no Gradient is applied to the examples provided. I am asking how I could apply one to each wave but have each wave share the Gradient so that they line up to look like 1 single element.

Comment: I was talking about the first image you are showing

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see what you are talking about now. Could you make an example usage? If you think it's a method to approach this, you could make it an answer,

Comment: @TemaniAfif Also, the first SVG wave is fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the entire container with a rectangle, having a linear gradient at angle. Then you can add your waves and animate them.

If you need to show waves in the smaller inner rectangle either add another one or use clipping with the clipped area dimensions.

Either way, here's a start:

```
<div id='container' style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
    <svg class='waves' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 200 200' preserveAspectRatio='none' shape-rendering='auto'>
        <defs>
            <path id='wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' />
            <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="1" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#E863BA" />
                <stop offset="100" stop-color="#211D2F" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#gradient1)"></rect>
        <g class='parallax'>
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='140' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='143' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='145' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='147' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)' />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```